# Cast varchar type to date

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.1, type-conversion

I'd like to change a specific column in my PostgreSQL database from `character_varying` type to type `date`. Date is in the format `yyyy:mm:dd`

I tried to do:

```
alter table table_name
alter column date_time type date using (date_time::text::date);
```

But I received an error message:

> date/time field value out of range: "2011:06:15"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you cast `text` or `varchar` to `date`, the default date format of your installation is expected - depending on the [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting of your session, typically set in your `postgresql.conf`. If in doubt, check with:

```
 SHOW datestyle;
```

Generally, colon (`:`) is a *time* separator, In a simple cast, PostgreSQL will probably try to interpret '2011:06:15' as time - and fail.

To **remove ambiguity** use [**`to_date()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) with a matching pattern for your dates:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN date_time type date
USING to_date(date_time, 'YYYY:MM:DD');  -- pattern for your example
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! But now I have the same problem with the hour column. It's a string and I'd like to trasform it in time type, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me even with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LoBizzarri: Piece of cake with `to_timestamp()`. Did you follow the link I provided? If it's still giving you static, post another question with example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Sorry, yesterday I had made ​​a mistake in the command line. Now it is ok, thanks! I used:
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN hour_time type time
USING to_timestamp(hour_time, 'HH24:MI:SS');