# Change column type from character varying to timestamp without time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, datetime, types

In Rails I created a string column called `open_time`, but then I realized I should use the `datetime` type. I did:

```
change_column :polls, :open_time, :datetime
```

But it said:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  column "open_time" cannot be cast to type timestamp without time zone
> : ALTER TABLE "polls" ALTER COLUMN "open_time" TYPE timestamp

If I just drop the string column and add new datetime column, I will lose the data stored in the string column. Alternatively, in PostgreSQL I can add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE polls ADD COLUMN published_time timestamp;
```

Ant then try to get the data from the string column like:

```
UPDATE polls SET published_time = strToTimeStamp(open_time);
```

Are there any functions I can use as `strToTimeStamp` to convert `character varying` type to `timestamp without time zone`?

Comment: You want `ALTER COLUMN ... USING` . See eg http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D%20ALTER%20COLUMN%20using (near-dup)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> .. are there any functions I can use as `strToTimeStamp` that can convert
> `character varying` type to `timestamp without time zone type`?

Use [**`to_timestamp()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to convert string data to type `timestamp` and alter the data type of the column in place:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col TYPE timestamp
USING to_timestamp(col, '<your pattern here>');
```

See:

- [Alter character field to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099352/alter-character-field-to-date-in-postgres/8099692)
- [Cast varchar type to date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13287618/939860)

Answer (score -3):

Don't think you can do that, since it's limited by capability of database. The idea is doing following:

- Created a new column with a different name
- Copy over the column contents after data convert for each row
- Drop the original col
- Rename the new col to to the original col name

These steps can be placed into same migration file and keep them into a transaction for in case.

Comment: You right, using DB capailibity can do that, but it's about using rails. Even we can use raw SQL to change the database column within rails migration, somehow it's not a good practice unless we are clearly understand the project is focus on a certain database.