# Error converting character varying column type to time in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to alter a column "event_time" from character varying to time data type. the data in the column is in format '00:10:30'.

I am getting the following error:-
ERROR:  invalid value ":3" for "SS"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.

Comment: well , you not showing how you did it, this might help , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287618/cast-varchar-type-to-date

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shown us what have you tried, I am only guessing here.

**[Rextester Demo1](http://rextester.com/UMDT94104)**

[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/HPLYP21826)

The problem while converting `00:10:31` to a `date` is not possible directly as there is no `date` part attached to the `time` part.

So you have to hardcode a date to the time part before casting it as `date`. So while conversion you have to use

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN event_time 
   TYPE DATE using to_date('1901-01-01 '||event_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Check the demo above for more. Check Demo2 to see the difference between two.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the column by casting it to TIME data type via the `USING` clause as illustrated below:

```
CREATE TABLE time_test (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    event_time CHARACTER VARYING(8) NULL
);

INSERT INTO time_test VALUES (1, '00:10:30');

\d time_test
                    Table "public.time_test"
      Column      |            Type             |       Modifiers        
------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 id               | integer                     | not null
 event_time       | character varying(8)        | 

SELECT * FROM time_test;
 id | event_time 
----+------------
  1 | 00:10:30
(1 row)

-- Alter column from CHARACTER VARYING to TIME
ALTER TABLE time_test ALTER COLUMN event_time TYPE TIME USING (event_time::TIME);

\d time_test
                    Table "public.time_test"
      Column      |            Type             |       Modifiers        
------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 id               | integer                     | not null
 event_time       | time without time zone      | 

SELECT * FROM time_test;
 id | event_time 
----+------------
  1 | 00:10:30
(1 row)
```

Please be advised to backup the table before schema changes like this.